# Multiple selection using text input - parameter don't work

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

In this example [LIVE DEMO](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html) column 0 (called *Some Data*) have these parameters:

```
    {
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "multi_select",
        select_type: 'select2'
    },
```

With this parameter you can do multiple selection using text input:

[image: multiple]

I try implement `select_type: 'select2'` parameter but it doesn't work for my table.

I look **jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js**, I find `multi_select_custom_func` but this is not correct parameter to solve problem.
This is my table: [MY TABLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/13/)

This is my rilevant javascript code:

```
    var oTable;
$(document).ready(function () {

'use strict';


    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true
    }).yadcf([{

        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "multi_select",
        select_type: 'multi_select_custom_func'
    }, {
        column_number: 4,
        filter_type: "range_number_slider",
        filter_container_id: "external_filter_container"
    }, {
        column_number: 3,
        text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }, {
        column_number: 1,

        filter_type: "multi_select"
    }, {
        column_number: 2,
        text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }, {
        column_number: 5,
        column_data_type: "html",
        html_data_type: "text",
        filter_default_label: "Select tag",
        filter_type: "auto_complete"


    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using wrong values for the wrong attributes,

Take a look at the docs [select_type -  Possible values:    chosen / select2](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L153) , continues reading and notice that the `multi_select_custom_func` can be set for the [filter_type](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L33) only.

Anyway the problem in your case is that you haven't included the select2 js/css and you haven't set the `select_type: 'select2'`

Here's an [updated/fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/14/)

Comment: Yup, it works, thanks. But I try also a solution to implement `column_number 5` with filter_type: *"multi_select"* and *select_type: 'select2'* **keeping onclick event**. Problem is that onclick event doesn't work if I click on it. So if I want select multiple tags keeping its onclick event feature in your table is not possible. **label.lightblue** inside column 5 is working only with *auto_complete* filter and this is very limiting. Every time that I click over tags instead row I would like to see added inside multi_select filter like for column 0 and 1.

Comment: @user3520363 , you need to start reading the docs, for multi select you have to provide different arguments for the `yadcf.exFilterColumn` function , copy paste from docs: `yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0, ['Some Data 1','Some Data 2']]]); // for pre filtering multi select filter you should use array with values (or an array with single value)`

Comment: I missing always something although I read the doc, sorry..For `label.lightblue` inside column 5 with *auto_complete* filter I have this javascript code `yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[5, $(this).text()]]);` but for column 5 I wish multi select filter like for column 0. I try to insert `yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[5, ['click','label.lightblue']]]);` but don't work. I try to keep onclick event for tags inside table rows when I use multi select filter but something is wrong. Can you update jsfiddle for column 5, please? I have 2 arguments to insert: onclick event and label.lightblue

Comment: onclick event functions don't work anymore for column 5, look this example please http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/16/ I create a new question because multi_filter have conflicts with onclick events http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169327/onclick-event-not-work-with-multi-select-filter-javascript