# onclick event not work with multi_select filter - javascript

Tags: javascript, yadcf

I read docs here for [filter_type](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L33) but I don't understand how provide thiese arguments

- **onclick event**
- **label.lightblue** (or *label2.lightblue2..*)

for yadcf.exFilterColumn if I want to set

```
filter_type: "multi_select":
select_type: 'select2'
```

My code is this:

```
 $('#example').on('click', ".label.lightblue", function () {

        yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [
            [5, $(this).text()]
        ]);
  });
```

This is my table: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/14/)
Look last column, please. If you click on a tag inside row table you can filtering rows.
I change filter_type from auto_complete to multi_select

```
column_number: 5,
column_data_type: "html",
html_data_type: "text",
filter_default_label: "Select tag",
filter_type: "multi_select":
select_type: 'select2'
```

But if you click now on tags inside table rows onclick event functions don't work anymore for column 5, look this example: [ONCLICK EVENT freezing](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/16/)

[image: onclick freezing]

I try to change

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[5, $(this).text()]]);
```

into

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[5, ['click','label.lightblue']]]);
```

but don't work

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore your question because I'm not sure why you ended up trying the stuff you wrote there

The difference in your current scenario in which you want to trigger multi selct filter from the table row itself is that now instead of providing the text of the clicked element you need to provide an array with a single value which is that text you are familiar with, **BUT** if you want to make the click on row to add selections to your filters so if suppose you click on Tag1 and then on Tag2, you expect to see the filter populated with Tag1 and Tag2 you need to make the following:

Each time you click on the column value (Tag1 / Tag2 / etc, you must extract the current selected value of that column using the [yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(...)](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L200) , then add to this array your newly clicked value , and only then call the `exFilterColumn` function (with the new array that you just constructed.

If you will follow my instruction it should work just fine